# GA4 Event Reporting Not Showing Today's Events

Tags: google-analytics-4

This seems simple, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

I'm doing some reporting out of GA4 to track volume of users to our pages along with events like conversions. All reports only go up to the prior day though, and do not report on current day volume.

Is this limitation standard to GA4, or are there settings I can adjust to make this accounted for? As a note, our events are fired from Google Tag Manager.

Comment: This is a feature; not a bug. You won't be able to see "real-time" or complete same-day data in your reports. Here is Google docs on freshness: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11198161?hl=en. I believe you  might be able to link your Ga4 to BigQuery and get more realtime data for a Looker Report.

Comment: Thank you @A_Patterson! I thought this might be the case, but none of my search results were yielding an explanation like this.

Comment: @A_Patterson please make your comment an answer. That's a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature; not a bug. You won't be able to see "real-time" or complete same-day data in your reports. Here is Google docs on freshness: [support.google.com/analytics/answer/11198161?hl=en](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11198161?hl=en). I believe you might be able to link your Ga4 to BigQuery and get more real-time data for a Looker Report.

However, if you do go the route of BigQuery, make sure you are aware of the free limits and if you will incure any additional charges.

Comment: If you set up the 'intraday' option of the BQ feed you will get data in near real time for reporting/visualisation in Looker Studio.